vuetify v-form passes validation when it shouldn't
I'm currently making a sign up form that should only submit when all input fields pass the validation. I've written rules to validate the fields and they are working as intended. The problem lies in the signUp() method that is called when the submit button is clicked. Even if one of the fields is left blank, this.$refs.form.validate() still evaluates to true (the success alert shows up) and I'm not sure why.
<v-card class="mt-10 m-5 bg-light-blue-lighten-3" elevation="4">
  <v-card-title class="text-center">Sign Up</v-card-title>
  <v-container class="bg-white" fluid>
    <v-form ref="form" fast-fail class="mx-5 my-4" >
      <v-text-field class="my-1
        v-model="username" label="Username" :rules="requiredRule">
      </v-text-field>
      <v-text-field 
        class="my-1" 
        v-model="password" label="Create Password" 
        :rules="[...requiredRule, ...pwRule]"
        :append-inner-icon="show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
        :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'"
        @click:append-inner="show = !show">
      </v-text-field>
      <v-text-field type="password" class="my-1"
        v-model="confirm_pw" label="Re-enter Password"
        :rules="[...requiredRule, ...matchRule]">
      </v-text-field>
      <div class="d-flex justify-center mt-4">
        <v-btn elevation="4" @click="signUp">Submit</v-btn>
      </div>
    </v-form>
    <v-alert v-if="msg == 'success'" type="success"
      title="Success"
      text="Successfully signed up."
      class="ma-2"
      :height="60">
    </v-alert>
    <v-alert v-if="msg && msg != 'success'"
      type="error"
      title="Error"class="ma-2"
      :height="60"
    >
      {{msg}}
    </v-alert>
  </v-container>
</v-card>

data() {
  return {
    show:false,
    msg:'',
    username:'',
    password:'',
    confirm_pw: '',
    requiredRule:[v => !!v || "This field is required."],
    pwRule:[v => !!v && v.length >=6 ||  "Password must be at least 6 characters long."],
    matchRule:[v => v === this.password || "Passwords must match."]
  }
},
methods: {
  signUp() {
  if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
    this.msg = "success";
  }
  else {
    this.msg = "error";
  }
}


Are the [...requiredRule, ...pwRule] rules not working or is it the requiredRule one?

@kissu they seem to be working as it returns the error message when my input is invalid. However even when the input field is 'invalid', this.$refs.form.validate() still evaluates to true.

Make the conditional on the submit yourself then.

What's the problem? your code seems work as expected:

You are passing in a single element array inside the rules prop array parameter. One way to fix this is to change your data to:
data() {
  return {
    show:false,
    msg:'',
    username:'',
    password:'',
    confirm_pw: '',
    requiredRule:v => !!v || "This field is required.",
    pwRule:v => !!v && v.length >=6 ||  "Password must be at least 6 characters long.",
    matchRule:v => v === this.password || "Passwords must match."
  }
},

